# Can I run a C# assembly (dll) as 32bit from a 64bit application?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, c#-2.0, codedom

I'm actually doing this with helper executables that are 32bit. But can I do it with DLLs that run on 32bit CodeDOM?

Comment: "32bit CodeDOM" doesn't mean anything.  The bitness of the process is locked in by the EXE.  Mixing is not supported, you need the helper EXE.

Comment: This is effectively a duplicate of [32bit dll in 64bit application in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478904/32bit-dll-in-64bit-application-in-c-sharp). The key bit of the chosen answer there is *A process in Windows is either 32- or 64-bit and it can only load DLLs which match. Any attempt to load a DLL which does not match will fail and produce an error.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, this helps you [Calling 32bit Code from 64bit Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128445/calling-32bit-code-from-64bit-process)

But it's better to call 32bit from separate 32bit process, and your 64bit code could start it and communicate with it